# Django Unittests Client Login: fails in test suite, but not in Shell

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm running a basic test of my home view. While logging the client in from the shell works, the same line of code fails to log the client in when using the test suite.

*What is the correct way to log the client in when using the Django test suite?*

Or

*Any idea why the client is not logging in with my current method?*

Shell test:

```
import unittest
from django.test.client import Client
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment
setup_test_environment()

client = Client()
login = client.login(username='agconti', password='password')

# login --> evals to True
```

Django test suite:

```
#### View Tests ####
import unittest
from django.test.client import Client
from shopping_cart.models import Store, Order, Item, Transaction

class Home_ViewTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        # login user
        login = self.client.login(username='agconti', password='password')
        # Check login
        self.assertEqual(login, True)

    def test_details(self):
        # get the home view
        response = self.client.get('/')      
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        # Check that the rendered context is not none 
        self.assertTrue(response.context['stores'] != None)

# self.assertEqual(login, True) --> login evals to False, raises the assertion
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A test user should be created.  Something like:

```
  def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()
    self.username = 'agconti'
    self.email = 'test@test.com'
    self.password = 'test'        
    self.test_user = User.objects.create_user(self.username, self.email, self.password)
    login = self.client.login(username=self.username, password=self.password)
    self.assertEqual(login, True)
```

In your shell test the user is probably already present in your db, whereas in your unittest there might not be a user...

Comment: Gotya, thanks. This works great. To anyone else looking at this make sure you import user with `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`.

Comment: Should this be used once per `test.py` file? In my own `create_test_user` test perhaps? if I run multiple tests I get an error that the user id isnt unique.

Comment: @agconti I'm running into that duplicate user issue as well. Did you manage to solve that?

Comment: @Roger yes, I believe this solved it for me. Are you running into more of an issue?

Comment: @agconti Yes. I have one TestCase class with multiple test methods. The first method runs ok but subsequent methods fail complaining about duplicate entries for the user that is created during setUp()... I would expect setUp to run only once and thus only create a user once.

Comment: @Roger setUp runs between each test case. To fix it add a tearDown where you delete the user. basically just put self.test_user.delete() in tearDown

Comment: @agconti Thanks. That works. I made one public test... method and then called private _test... methods which works as well. Like your approach better.